# Calculating derivative in a given point - matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative

I would like to calculate the derivative of the following function in Matlab in point x=1.0:

```
 v = sin(x)+ cos(3*x)
```

I tried this but it returns py = []

```
sym x,
x=1.0,
y=sin(x) + cos(3*x),
py=diff(y);
```

Comment: The line `sym x` doesn't create a symbolic variable `x` like you want. As you can see from the answers, the proper command is `sums x` (or `x = sym('x');`). And you'll need to evaluate the symbolic derivative using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
syms x
y=sin(x)+cos(3*x);
py=diff(y);
subs(py,x,1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple functions in Matlab called diff. Important for this question is the "standard" diff, which is for vecor/matrix input. This is what you called. If you read the documentation, you will understand the empty output: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/diff.html

Suitable for your case is the symbolic toolbox: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/diff.html The examples explain how to use, if the toolbox is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
syms x real
v = sin(x)+ cos(3*x)
diff(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a simple function `v(x) = sin(x)+ cos(3*x)` just use the explicit formula for its derivative, i.e. `vv = dv/dx = cos(x) - 3*sin(3*x)`.

Then its value in x = 1.0 is: `vv(1.0) = cos(1.0) - 3*sin(3*1.0)`.